# What are PyCharm actions when it runs a python script?

Tags: python, pycharm

#### 1. What does Pycharm do when I run a python script?

My hypothesis - in the default configuration PyCharm does the following:

- Adds source and content roots to the `PYTHONPATH`.
- Switch working directory to the directory of the script.
- Run the script.

Because that project root is a content root, it will be added to the `PYTHONPATH` and relative imports will work (relative to the project root).

#### 2. Is there a way to easily replicate this from a terminal?

Ideas:

- Run `python -m scripts.some_script` from the project root. Relative imports will work, but the working directory will be the project root.
- Permamently project root to `PYTHONPATH`, run the script from its folder.

#### 3. Alternatively, change PyCharm configuration?

I guess there is a good reason why PyCharm configuration is exactly what it is now, but if not, maybe it makes sense to always set working directory to the root of the project?

---

My motivation: I am doing a small scientific project. I want to run my simulations on a remote machine using SSH, and I cannot spend too much time to set it up. The project code is constantly updated via git. New parts (new simulations) are frequently added to the project.

Comment: Why don't you use PyCharm's remote interpreter support to run the scripts on your remote machine?

Comment: This could be a solution. However, 1) that is good idea to be able to run my code independently on IDE 2) I don't own a Professional version at the moment 3) I might need to run my code on high computing cluster, and for that I will probably have to use some master script anyway. So I will have to duplicate exactly what PyCharm does, if I want my code to run correctly.